# Transparent part of image blocks background color in PyQt5

Tags: python, image, pyqt, pyqt5, transparent

I am in the process of learning PyQt5 by translating a previously written Tkinter music player application.  One of the configuration options allows the user to set the background color of all buttons.  However, three of the buttons (Play, Pause & Stop) are unique as they also display a corresponding image.  The image consists of an icon on a transparent background where the icon is colored (Play=green, Pause=yellow, Stop=red) for when a given state is active or white if one of the other two states is active.  Below is what the (active) Play button looks like on Tkinter for a couple of different background settings:
[image: sample background #1]

and

[image: sample background #2]

On Qt5 I have verified that the background color is being set correctly by commenting out the line that loads the image:

[image: background only - no image]

However, when the same image file from Tkinter is loaded, the background color is suddenly blocked in the sections of the image that are transparent:

[image: image and background]

When my initial attempt didn't work, I tracked down [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56661822/background-image-overrides-background-color-of-pushbutton?noredirect=1&lq=1) post and modified my code from the way the original code was being done to the way suggested in the answer.  However, in my case this made no difference.  The code I'm using to test this is (with image load commented out):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        btn = QPushButton(self)
        btn.resize(70,70)
        btn.move(115, 115)
        btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: #b5abf4")
        btn.setObjectName("widget")
        #btn.setStyleSheet("#widget{background-image: url(play_on.png)}")
        
        self.setGeometry(600, 300, 300, 300)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
        self.show()
        
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm still very much a novice on Qt but everything I've read so far seems to indicate that this should work.  Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setStyleSheet()` always overwrites the previously set stylesheet for that widget, so you are basically ignoring the previous `setStyleSheet()` call. Also, since you're setting the `background-color` for the parent stylesheet, it will automatically propagate that background for its children (since stylesheets are, indeed, *cascading*).

To correctly set the stylesheet you have to set the background color **and** background image within the same call.

```
        btn.setStyleSheet('''
            #widget {
                background-color: #b5abf4;
                background-image: url(play_on.png);
            }
            ''')
```

Since you'll probably want to set those backgrounds for all buttons and avoid setting the stylesheets individually each time, you can use object properties and the `[property="value"]` selector in the parent stylesheet

```
        btn.setObjectName("playButton")
        btn.setProperty('mediabutton', True)
        btn.setStyleSheet('''
            #playButton {
                background-image: url(play_on.png);
            }
            ''')
        
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            Example {
                /* set the background *only* for the parent widget */
                background-color: white;
            }
            QPushButton[mediabutton="true"] {
                /* set the background color for all push buttons that
                have the "mediabutton" property set to True */
                background-color: #b5abf4;
            }
        ''')
```

Comment: That did it and thanks for the information that setStyleSheet() is not additive - I had not realized that.